# How to remove a customized object using stl remove from container set?

Tags: c++, stl, set, remove-if

Following is the class and container

```
class student {
    std::string name;
    int id;
}

set<Student*, compare> s; // sorted by id that i have done correctly
class compare {
public:
    bool operator()( Student* s1, Student* s2) {
        return s1->id < s2->id;
    }
};
```

How to remove a object from set having some name = "suri";

What I did?

```
std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), nameIs("suri"));
```

functor is

```
struct nameIs {
    nameIs ( std::string s ) : toFind(s) { }
    bool operator() ( Student* st)
    { return st->name.compare(toFind) == 0; }
    std::string toFind;
};
```

But I am getting compile time error
Error   2   error C3892: '_Next' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    1816

What wrong am i doing?
How to remove a customized object using stl remove from container set?

Comment: I have added compare also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

if u look at it, `*first == val` but actually in ur case, it shud be `*first->name == val`

well , u can try this

```
std::set<Student*>::iterator it = s.begin();
for (it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ) {
     if ((*it)->name == "suri") {
        s.erase(it++);
         break;
    }
    else {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Comment: can't I use any stl function like remove?

Answer (score 1):

As @pola sai ram pointed out, you can't sue `std::remove` because that requires the elemetns to be assignable.

However, you **don't need remove**:
`std::remove` doesn't really remove elements from your container, but only copies all elments you want to keep to the front (see [erase-remove-idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)). For the actual removal, you always have to use a container specific `erase` function anyway. So in your case, you can just use `find_if` as a replacement for `remove`. The drawback is that you have to call it multiple times:

```
auto it = std::find_if(begin(s), end(s), nameIs("suri"));
while (it != end(s)){
    it = s.erase(it);
    it = std::find_if(it, end(s), nameIs("suri"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Such algorithm has been [proposed](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n4273.htm) and added to [Library Fundamentals 2 TS](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4481.html). If your compiler supports Library Fundamentals 2 TS, you could `#include` `<experimental/set>` and use `std::experimetal::erase_if(s, nameIs("suri"))`.